# Is there a hook to put stylesheet and/or JS inside iframes (thickbox or tinyMCE) in admin area

Tags: admin, hooks, tinymce, thickbox, iframe

I'm working on my admin area theme and I wanted to make some modifications on the way the thickbox and tinyMCE looks. I could make most of the changes through adding custom stylesheets and JS to my admin area using `wp_enqueue_script()` and `wp_enqueue_style()`, but I have had a hard time making some others changes. This is because the iframes containing the elements are either not reachable by my own styles or have in their head some other stylesheet and JS that override mine.

I more or less managed to bypass that using some JavaScript and the CSS `!important` declaration but I was wondering if there was any hooks that would allow me to call `wp_enqueue_script()` and `wp_enqueue_style()` to put my scripts inside those iframes headers? Some hook similar to `admin_head` or `admin_init` but for the thickbox or iframes?

Answer (score 3):

You could over-ride the CSS by using the <strike>admin_print_scripts</strike> `admin_head-media-upload-popup` and add css to match your needs. This can be done via the functions.php file or by creating a plugin. Here is the code in a plugin format to begin adding style:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Some Name
Description: Custom Thickbox Styles
*/
add_action('admin_head-media-upload-popup', 'custom_tb_styles');
function custom_tb_styles() {
  ?>
  <style>
    #TB_window {
    background:silver;
    }
    /*
    YOUR CUSTOM STYLES HERE
    */
  </style>
  <?php
  }
```

If you're adding the code to your functions.php file you could just add this to the file:

```
<?php
add_action('admin_head-media-upload-popup', 'custom_tb_styles');
function custom_tb_styles() {
  ?>
  <style>
    #TB_window {
    background:silver;
    }
    /*
    YOUR CUSTOM STYLES HERE
    */
  </style>
  <?php
  }
```

Another option is to unregister the Thickbox Styles and completely add your own.

_Edited according to the comment by **ungestaltbar**, which points to the correct hook to print the style/script only in the thickbox iframe. The action hooks used earlier (`admin_print_scripts` & `admin_print_styles`) will be called in **all** administrative pages.

Comment: better hook for the thickbox might be: 
    add_action('admin_head-media-upload-popup','function');

Comment: @ungestaltbar : great hook highlighting, thanks for that!

Answer (score 2):

For TinyMCE, there is a specific function [add_editor_style()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_editor_style) for enqueuing a stylesheet in the visual editor. If you call that in `functions.php` you just put `editor-style.css` in your theme folder and you're good to go. Otherwise, the function accepts an arg of a custom stylesheet name.

Comment: This was best for me.